# Implementing a Steepest Descent Algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numerical-methods

I am teaching myself some coding, and as my first "big" project I tried implementing a Steepest Descent algorithm to minimize the Rosenbrock function:

$$f(x, y) = 100 (y - x^2)^2 + (1 - x)^2$$

The algorithm goes like this: We start with an initial guess \$x_0\$ (vector). We update the guess using the formula

$$x_{k+1} = x_k - alpha (\nabla f(x_k) \cdot \nabla f(x_k))$$

where alpha is to be chosen so that is satisfies the Armijo condition. We keep repeating until we reach a point where the gradient is less than 0.1 in both components.

Could you please tell me any ways in which I could improve my algorithm? In particular, I'm looking to increase its speed. From the current starting point, it takes about 30 seconds to run on my computer (16GM ram, i7 processor).

**Remark:** The reason I keep using `np.array([[1, 2, 3]])` for vectors is so that I can transpose and matrix multiply them at will. I'm not sure if this is a good practice.

```
# This program uses the Steepest Descent Method to 
# minimize the Rosenbrock function
import numpy as np

# Define the Rosenbrock Function
def f(x_k):
    x, y = x_k[0, 0], x_k[0, 1] 
    return 100 * (y - x**2)**2 + (1 - x)**2

# Gradient of f 
def gradient(x_k):
    x, y = x_k[0, 0], x_k[0, 1] 
    return  np.array([[-400*x*(y-x**2)-2*(1-x), 200*(y-x**2)]])


def main():
    # Define the starting guess
    x_k = np.array([[10, 5]])
    # Define counter for number of steps
    numSteps = 0

    # Keep iterating until both components of the gradient are less than 0.1 in absolute value
    while abs((gradient(x_k)[0, 0])) > 0.1 or abs((gradient(x_k))[0, 1]) > 0.1:
        numSteps = numSteps + 1

        # Step direction
        p_k = - gradient(x_k)
        gradTrans = - p_k.T

        # Now we use a backtracking algorithm to find a step length
        alpha = 1.0
        ratio = 0.8
        c = 0.01 # This is just a constant that is used in the algorithm

        # This loop selects an alpha which satisfies the Armijo condition  
        while f(x_k + alpha * p_k) > f(x_k) + (alpha * c * (gradTrans  @ p_k))[0, 0]:
            alpha = ratio * alpha

        x_k = x_k + alpha * p_k

    print("The number of steps is: ", numSteps)
    print("The final step is:", x_k)
    print("The gradient is: ", gradient(x_k))

main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
# Define the Rosenbrock Function
def f(x_k):
    x, y = x_k[0, 0], x_k[0, 1] 
    return 100 * (y - x**2)**2 + (1 - x)**2
```

could be

```
def f_rosenbrock(xy):
    x, y = xy
    return 100 * (y - x**2)**2 + (1 - x)**2
```

This

```
# Gradient of f 
def gradient(x_k):
    x, y = x_k[0, 0], x_k[0, 1] 
    return  np.array([-400*x*(y-x**2)-2*(1-x), 200*(y-x**2)])
```

could be

```
def df_rosenbrock(xy):
    x, y = xy
    return  np.array([-400*x*(y-x**2)-2*(1-x), 200*(y-x**2)])
```

It wouldn't cost much to turn `main` into a more general gradient descent function having the following signature:

```
def gradient_descent(f, d_f, x0):
    # Define the starting guess
    x_k = x0
    # ...
```

You could add the following condition so that this code won't run if imported as a module.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # main()
    gradient_descent(f_rosenbrock, df_rosenbrock, np.array([10, 5]))
```

It'd probably be the best to stick to either `camelCase` or `snake_case` for variable names. The second is more popular. E.g. `num_steps` instead of `numSteps`.

Don't evaluate the gradient so many times:

```
    while abs((gradient(x_k)[0, 0])) > 0.1 or abs((gradient(x_k))[0, 1]) > 0.1:
        # ...
        p_k = - gradient(x_k)
        gradTrans = - p_k.T

        # ...
    print("The gradient is: ", gradient(x_k))
```

could be

```
    while True:
        g_k = df(x_k)

        if np.abs(g_k).max() < tol:
            break    
    # ...
    print("The gradient is: ", g_k)
```

We don't need `gradTrans`, nor `p_k`.

This

```
    # Now we use a backtracking algorithm to find a step length
    alpha = 1.0
    ratio = 0.8
    c = 0.01 # This is just a constant that is used in the algorithm

    # This loop selects an alpha which satisfies the Armijo condition  
    while f(x_k + alpha * p_k) > f(x_k) + (alpha * c * (gradTrans  @ p_k))[0, 0]:
        alpha = ratio * alpha

    x_k = x_k + alpha * p_k
```

part is probably the worst offender wrt. performance. You don't have to recalculate all of these values. Some constants are hardcoded, while they could easily become parameters.

Anyway, putting it all together we get something like the following.
Feel free to add comments to it, but use docstrings whenever appropriate.

```
import numpy as np

def f_rosenbrock(xy):
    x, y = xy
    return 100 * (y - x**2)**2 + (1 - x)**2

def df_rosenbrock(xy):
    x, y = xy
    return np.array([-400*x*(y-x**2)-2*(1-x), 200*(y-x**2)])

def gradient_descent(f, df, x0, tol=.1, alpha=1.0, ratio=.8, c=.01):
    x_k, num_steps, step_size = x0, 0, alpha
    while True:
        g_k = df(x_k)

        if np.abs(g_k).max() < tol:
            break

        num_steps += 1

        fx, cg = f(x_k), - c * (g_k**2).sum()
        while f(x_k - step_size * g_k) > fx + step_size * cg:
            step_size *= ratio

        x_k -= step_size * g_k

    return x_k, g_k, num_steps

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x, g, n = gradient_descent(
        f_rosenbrock, df_rosenbrock, np.array([10.0, 5.0])
    )
    print("The number of steps is: ", n)
    print("The final step is:", x)
    print("The gradient is: ", g)
```

Comment: Thanks, your feedback is increadibly helpful!

Answer (score 4):

You biggest time waster appears to be this loop:

```
    while f(x_k + alpha * p_k) > f(x_k) + (alpha * c * (gradTrans  @ p_k))[0, 0]:
        alpha = ratio * alpha
```

`f(x_k)`, `c`, `gradTrans`, and `p_k` are all constant in the loop, so you can compute `f(x_k)` and `c * (gradTrans @ p_k)` before the loop and use these computed values in the test expression, instead of recomputing the same values over and over.

```
    fxk = f(x_k)
    offset = c * (gradTrans @ p_k)
    while f(x_k + alpha * p_k) > fxk + (alpha * offset)[0, 0]:
        alpha = ratio * alpha
```

Doing so cuts the time roughly in half.

Similarly, `gradient(x_k)` is computed 3 times here:

```
while abs((gradient(x_k)[0, 0])) > 0.1 or abs((gradient(x_k))[0, 1]) > 0.1:
    ...
    p_k = - gradient(x_k)
```

Again, compute once and store the result.

---

You should probably use vectors instead of matrices:

```
    x_k = np.array([10., 5.])
```

Which can be unpacked using tuple assignment:

```
def f(x_k):
    x, y = x_k 
    return 100 * (y - x**2)**2 + (1 - x)**2
```

And using `10.` and `5.` in the above `x_k` initialization makes the arrays `float64` instead of `int32`, which allows you to use in-place addition operators:

```
        x_k += alpha * p_k
```

instead of:

```
        x_k = x_k + alpha * p_k
```

Comment: Argh, you beat me to it. :(

Comment: Ya, but you wrote a better answer.

Comment: Hardly better, just longer..

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback!